# Error in declaring the interface in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have imported a Table with pagination component in my project. I am getting this error:

> Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.

It's showing an error because of this interface code:

```
export  interface PeriodicElement {
 name: string;
 position: number;
 weight: number;
 symbol: string;
}
```

I have seen many suggestions for fixing the same error in Stack Overflow, but nothing worked for me. I am aware about the concept of interfaces, but it is new to me. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Are you declaring an interface in the separate file?

Comment: I was created `export  interface PeriodicElement {
 .....
}`                                                                                                                   inside another class `export class EditSessionComponent implements OnInit {              
    }` so the error was coming, Now its solved.

Answer (score 1):

Your provided code works without error:

[image]

You are probably using the `interface` in a place where `A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.` An `interface` is none of these things.